# Moving a whole server into docker instance (or LXC)

Tags: debian, virtual-machine, lxc, docker

It seems to work, to [move an existing install into a virtual machine](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Moving_an_existing_install_into_%28or_out_of%29_a_virtual_machine#Moving_into_a_VM).

Is it possible to move a whole Debian server into a docker instance inside the same machine?

I would like to get a docker that I could download to my local computer to do some tests on the same system.

I want to test if a migration from syscp to froxol and the dist-upgrade to debian jessie will work before I will do it to the live system.

Can I achieve this with docker without a fresh install? or do I have to use LXC?